# Should that windows timeline show all my last activity from any app?

Tags: windows-10, timeline

I read some time ago about the Windows (10) Timeline (press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and scroll down to see it). As far I understood it: All programs should contribute to that Microsoft Graph, so that you can cross platform continue your work of any application (which provides that data).

Is that right or did Microsoft aim something else which I have missed?

If so is there a sample how that should look like in an ideal world?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applications must use the Timeline interface for it to show up in the Timeline.

I used QuickBooks and other small applications, none of which showed up and show no results when searched with Timeline Search

So the application must interface with Timeline or it will be lost to the timeline.